# JSON value '(1,"0.2")' of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to a ABI36_0_YGValue

Tags: react-native, expo

It happens when I click on a textInput and then focus on another textInput.
There is no info on where the error is generated,
however if I dismiss the error the application runs pefectly without errors.
I'm using EXPO SDK36

Thanks in advance.
[image: error_screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue.
Basically I've found that these kinds of errors are thrown with typos in styles.

In my case the error was related to LinearGradient package from Expo.

Changing `start = [1, 0.2]` to `start = {x:1, y:0.2}` solved my error.